# How to create Weather Forecast app?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, weather, weather-api, openweathermap

I'm trying to figure out how to create a Weather Forecast application using Windows Phone 8.1 and OpenWeatherMap API. But I couldn't find any document on how to start on this. Any help? It doesn't have to be OpenWeatherMap too. Just want to know how to make and app using a given time period and forecast for that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very vague, can you provide more detail, or indeed any code you may have.

I presume you have the required tools installed and have had a look at the samples over at https://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/oem?contentName=docs%2FGetting_Started%2FPreparing_for_Windows_Phone_development

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Yes I'm coding right now and I have implemented many features in an app I'm building. I want to add a feature where it'll show weather for an given future time period. But I don't know where to start. Only free API I found was OpenWeatherMap but I don't know how to use it with in Windows Phone. Can you refer any post where I can learn and start?

Comment: there are lots of weather API's available see http://www.programmableweb.com/news/26-weather-apis-12-support-json/2012/01/11, most of which are RestFul API's. If you are looking for help consuming a RestFul API, after some research of your own, I would raise a separate specific question about this. P.S great to see more developers looking at Windows Phone :-)